# Double to NSString conversion wrong

Tags: nsstring, double

```
double M=log(7);
M=pow(M_E,M);             // M = 7 !!!!!!

NSString *B = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M] stringValue]; // B=6.999999999 !!!!
```

But:

```
double M=7;
NSString *B = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M] stringValue]; // B=7
```

Why do these two examples produce different results?

Answer (score 1):

Floating point values cannot precisely represent every real number, so you'll often get very slightly off results like this. For example, `(1.0 / 3.0) * 3.0` does not precisely give 1.

Comment: I agree but;

if you debug the this codes;    double M=pow(M_E,log(7)); 

You can see M=7 in the Xcode debug window.

But following command wrong working and produce 6.99999999999

NSString *B = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:pow(M_E,log(7))] stringValue];

Comment: @BulentUNALMIS: So the debug window's routine for representing a double and NSNumber's `stringValue` are not identical.